# How to merge 2 matrices to get a single data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I was wondering what is the shortest way to go from `x1` and `x2` to my desired `data.frame` output shown below?

```
(x1 = matrix(c(1,3,2, 3,7,2),3,2)  )  
(x2 = matrix(c(4,6,6,5,5,4, 6,8,8,10,10,6),6,2)  ) 
colnames(x1) <- colnames(x2) <- c("SA", "CSA")


#-- Desired `data.frame` output:
#SA   CSA  group
#1    3     1
#3    7     1
#2    2     1
#4    6     2
#6    8     2
#6    8     2
#5    10    2
#5    10    2
#4    6     2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
x1<-as_tibble(x1)
x2<-as_tibble(x2)

a <- bind_rows(x1, x2, .id = "id")
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  id       SA   CSA
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1         1     3
2 1         3     7
3 1         2     2
4 2         4     6
5 2         6     8
6 2         6     8
7 2         5    10
8 2         5    10
9 2         4     6
```

Answer (score 0):

If using only base R, you could do:

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame,mapply(cbind,list(x1,x2),group = 1:2))

  SA CSA group
1  1   3     1
2  3   7     1
3  2   2     1
4  4   6     2
5  6   8     2
6  6   8     2
7  5  10     2
8  5  10     2
9  4   6     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do this.

```
df <- data.frame(rbind(x1, x2), 
                 "group" = rep(c(1, 2), 
                               times = c(dim(x1)[1], dim(x2)[1])))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to convert matrices into a list of dataframes an then pivot each list by id, by using `ldply()` from `library(plyr)`:

```
library(plyr)

# convert matrices in a list #
x <-list(x1=data.frame(x1),
         x2=data.frame(x2))

# pivot list elements by id #
ldply(x)
```

Console output:

```
#  .id SA CSA
#1  x1  1   3
#2  x1  3   7
#3  x1  2   2
#4  x2  4   6
#5  x2  6   8
#6  x2  6   8
#7  x2  5  10
#8  x2  5  10
#9  x2  4   6
```